# Efficiently copy names in shell

Tags: shell, filenames, mouse, clipboard

I have noticed an efficient technique that some users use to quickly copy directory and file names in the terminal or shell. The behavior/usage is as follows:

1. Issue `ls`
2. Click on the desired entry, followed possibly by a keystroke
3. This entry is automatically copied to the prompt.

I think this is very efficient.

Question 1: What tool can make the shell behave this way?

Question 2: Is there a way to do the same thing with Putty?

Comment: mouse middle button?

Comment: With Putty, highlighting text automatically copies it to the buffer.  Unlike (most) Linux distributions which use the middle mouse button or wheel-click, right-click is the default method for pasting.

Comment: Stéphane, yes, that's actually what I was looking for (and answers Q1 above). Digging deeper, I realized it's a selection paste rather than copy & paste. Timothy & drewbenn answered Q2. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont understand what you are asking but why dont you double click the word/filename that you want to use?  when you double click a word it will select the whole word.  You can setup breaks so like . or , or < or ( will stop the double click select.  These are configureable.  I dont have putty so i forget how to configure.  Google putty doubleclick word select.

In putty just double click the word/filename and then paste that in window via the normal paste method.  If you want to paste it back in putty i think its middle click, maybe right click.

Comment: Thanks, this answers Q2 above. Middle click doesn't work in Putty but right click does, as Tim pointed out above.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -t | sed q | xclip
```

for the latest file in the current directory in the buffer

Comment: Sputnick, my question turned out to involve something very basic. Sorry I made it confusing. Thanks for the suggestion about xclip!